# iPhone native apps - access to call logs, SMS, calendar, iTunes library

Tags: calendar, sms, accessibility, desktop, native

As I understand there aren't any public APIs available or any 'legal'/'official' way of accessing those...

I was just wondering how come some Desktop apps (MissingSync, iPhoneDrive) have access to those then...

UPDATE: I found that Desktop App still shows the most updated info from iPhone device, without having to sync/back-up the device to desktop. Which makes me conclude that the Desktop app must be fetching info directly from the device and NOT from the back-up residing on Desktop (Windows PC: `C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup`) Pls. correct me if am missing something here..)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because on the Desktop Apple has no way restricting a random application looking in a certain folder where the iPhone backup lives (Windows PC: C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Application Data\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup)  and reading information from it.

Comment: Not sure why this was modded down. This is exactly how they work -- by reading the backup residing on the PC/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

the iPhone stores those in SQLite databases. If the application has access to those files, it can access the data.

Comment: How can a application can access the path on jailbroken phone.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think it depends on the app and how crucial it is to have the most recent info - I've seen both done.

But I think getting the data directly from the phone is also possible as I found this project from Google - http://code.google.com/p/iphonebrowser/

Another way some apps do it is by asking your computer and your iPhone to be on the same network and then they also get direct access to iPhones filesystem (Things app does that and also the Apples own Remote app for iTunes)

Comment: so if getting the data directly from phone is possible with desktop application, why cant iPhone native application have access to iPhone fie system (for SMS log, call log, calender etc.) ? If Apple has not published (iPhones) APIs for that then what set of APIs these desktop applications are using?

Comment: I think it is for security... Since there are so many applications there is always a possibility that someone is using my information for something fishy... eg. collecting phonenumbers and emails for spamming or other personal information that I have about me and my contacts.

Comment: Plus there might be conflicts when at any given time tens of applications are using and modifing the same information..

Comment: thx texmex5 for discussions :-)

my confusion is: 'Technically' if Desktop applications can access iPhone file system, what prevents iPhone native apps to access same info ? cant be lack of APIs else how come Desktop apps can have access to it...

Comment: It's the sandbox each iOS app lives it that prevents it from accessing the whole filesystem. Regarding the desktop apps: Maybe (just a theory) the developers reverse engineered the protocol iTunes uses to communicate with a connected device. I guess iTunes has the necessary privileges to access anything on the device. The mentioned iphonebrowser works on jailbroken devices only btw.